# Importing objects as .dae in Xcode and using textures on them

Tags: texturing, uv, export, collada

I am beginning to learn how to model 3d models for games and am having troubles figuring out how this should be done. When googling I realized that most people use Collada exported files and that having troubles with them in Xcode is quite a common problem. If I understood correctly, exporting it will not apply textures directly on the model, but you can UV unwrap the model and then apply those unwraps as diffuse and normal maps in Xcode. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

The problem is when I try to apply some materials on selected object in Xcode, I don't get any options for materials, just a message that applying materials is not available.

Should I export the object in any particular way or apply the materials in code or something like this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like [this answer on using collada files](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14604/21825) in Xcode for SceneKit?   Are there any steps there that you missed?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get those options. I tried exporting an object that had no textures and did not UV unwrap it, could this be the problem?