# Material not appearing in Xcode

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials, export, scene

I added metal materials to my model in blender using principled bsdf shader. it looked fine in the rendered view. I exported to a .dae file and copied to Xcode following [the steps in this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/properly-export-collada-for-use-in-scenekit). when I run the app I just get a plain white model. The materials are in the hierarchy but its's not on the model.

Xcode also doesn't preview the model. I'm not sure why it's doing this but this is also happening for the included default 3D model. So if anyone knows how to fix this in addition please let me know.

**Update:** The cube should be a blue metal material [image]
[image]

Comment: [Possibly Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42246/textures-not-showing-after-collada-export)  No support for cycles materials.  Not sure this has changed.

Comment: I don’t think so because I can edit the properties of the material in the inspector and a preview should be coming up but I’m not sure why the previews aren’t working for me @batFINGER

Comment: Not using Xcode to be able to test.  At your end you couild try exporting cube with blender internal material / cycles material and see what results you get.

Comment: What do you mean exporting cube with cycles material? @batFINGER

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: It's not a duplicate if that (please don't mark this question as a duplicate). That question states that the materials aren't there at all. For me the materials are in Xcode, I can see them in the hierarchy it just not on the model @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Make a simple sample file. eg default cube with a uv map and texture.  Go thru the [steps outlined here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14584/properly-export-collada-for-use-in-scenekit)   Post the sample file, add some screenshots of result in xcode etc.  All we have to go by here is _"I've done everything right,... because I see the materials in the hierarchy,  but it's still wrong"_

Comment: Added screenshots. It doesn't allow me to attach files to the post but I can upload to dropbox and have a link if needed @batFINGER